# How to record screen on Windows Phone 7 as a video?

Tags: video, windows-phone-7, screen-capture

Does anyone know of a good way to record an application being used on Windows Phone 7 that includes markers as to where on the screen it is being touched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no public tool available to do this. Microsoft has them for sure since it was used at a couple of events (incluing PDC and other general presentations around the US), but it is not released anywhere else.

Your best bet is recording the screen data directly from the emulator via a desktop screen capture application.

Comment: I recently had a "developer mule" and had a look at the desktop video output. The mule had an option to use the USB for VGA output in Settings. This was a firmware setting and required a reboot of the device - and it also required special software running on the PC. I don't see this being available as a general option any point soon :(

Comment: @Dennis that unfortunate. This might be a good question to ask in wp7 forums. Maybe we could "suggest" they make this tool available.

Comment: As I said - I am fairly confient this option exists, it's just not public.

Comment: The tool that Microsoft use to mirror the screen display to video out will NOT be made publicaly available due to licensing issues. I have asked about this lots. ;)

Comment: Yeah they recommended I use Expression Encoder and record off the emulator. Guess that will have to work for now.

Comment: It also just hit me to change the cursor temporarily to simulate what they used. Ha brilliant.